Can X11 pass the identifiers/names of the involved pointers/keyboards when passing/generating input events? Do Tk/Gtk/Qt do too?
If I type xinput I get the following output:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard Consumer Control     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB Keyboard System Control       id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]

in other words, individual input devices have individual IDs & names. When receiving an input event, it is usually possible to differentiate whether it came from a mouse or a keyboard. But is it also possible to differentiate from which mouse or keyboard it came from? If possible in X11, does this carry over to Tk/Gtk/Qt?
